# if composite function is onto, show first transformation is onto

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A,B,C be finite dimensional vector spaces, and let S:B→C and T:A→B be linear transformations. Show that if ∘:A→C is onto and dimB≤dimC then  is onto.

Showing that S is onto is pretty straightforward:
Let c ∈ C. We must show that c ∈ Image(S). Since ST is onto, there is an a ∈ A such that
ST(a) = c. But then c = ST(a) = S(T(a)) by definition, so c ∈ Image(S).

With regards to T, I have no clue where to start. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The question doesn't make sense: if $S$ is a map from $A$ to $B$ and $T$ is a map from $B$ to $C$, then you can talk about $T\circ S$, but not necessarily about $S\circ T$.

Comment: Hi Jose, thank you for the correction. I mixed up S & T in the original question and have edited the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T$ is not surjective, then $\dim T(A)<\dim B$ and therefore$$\dim S\bigl(T(A)\bigr)\leqslant\dim T(A)<\dim B\leqslant\dim C.$$In particular, $\dim S\bigl(T(A)\bigr)<\dim C$. This is impossible, since $S\circ T$ is surjective, and therefore $S\bigl(T(A)\bigr)=C$.

Comment: great explanation, thank you!